# sending email with smtp (help needed)

Tags: python, smtp, discord.py

```
async def test(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    _smpt = smtplib.SMTP('mail.cock.li', 587)
    _smpt.starttls()
    username = ('my email@cock.li')
    password = ('my pass')
    try:
        _smpt.login(username, password)
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"incorrect password or email")
    reciever = (f'{arg1}')
    message = (f'{arg2}')
    _smpt.sendmail(username, reciever, message)
```

does anyone know why this is gving me a error im using https://cock.li/server and discord.py bot command

the error is `SMTPResponseException: (454, b'4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem')`

Comment: Did you try `telnet` to the target SMTP port and enter all the commands manually? If you are not familiar with the SMTP protocol, you should not try "low level" programming SMTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: change the security settings of your sender mail id such that it allows access to low security apps(can be done manually in mail settings)

Use the following code

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.starttls()
sender_email_id=input("sender mail")
sender_email_id_password=input("sender mail password")
s.login(sender_email_id, sender_email_id_password)
message = "Message_you_need_to_send"
receiver_email_id=input("receiver mail")
s.sendmail(sender_email_id, receiver_email_id, message)
s.quit()
```